# How to create empty wordpress permalink and redirect it into django website?

Tags: python, django, wordpress

I need to do such thing, but I don't even know if it is possible to accomplish and if so, how to do this.

I wrote an Django application which I would like to 'attach' to my wordpress blog. However, I need a permalink (but no page in wordpress pages section) which would point to Django application on the same server. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "Page links to" wordpress plugin to point to any url: https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. You will have to provide more info about what you are trying to accomplish to give the right advise.

- make a page with a redirect (this is an ugly solution in seo and user perspective)
- handle this on server level.
- load your Django data with an ajax call